# Правильно ли использован JOIN в SQL запросе?

Tags: sql

*Вывести имена всех сотрудников (Employees), которые участвовали в обработке заказов клиента по имени (CustomerName), Hanari Carnes.*

**`SELECT`** FirstName, LastName, CustomerName, CustomerID,
**`FROM`** Customers
**`JOIN`** Orders USING(CustomerID)
**`JOIN`** Employees USING(EmployeeID)
**`WHERE`** CustomerName = 'Hanari Carnes'

Правильно ли я связал столбцы?

[image: Наглядный вариант того, что получается.]

Comment: а где это вы так тренеруетесь? Подскажите пожалуйста ресурс

Comment: @had0uken Вот "тренировочный полигон" так сказать. Там нужно выбрать язык и можно даже изучать там же.
https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Если столбцы названы так как они в таблицах называются то правильно. Но вообще странно как запрос с картинки выполняется, там в первой строке в конце лишняя запятая и я бы на месте СУБД очень сильно захотел бы узнать какой именно CustomerID имеется ввиду в фразе select (из какой таблицы). А вообще нет смысла спрашивать так или нет, выполняете запрос и смотрите он дает ожидаемый результат или нет

Comment: @Misha Спасибо!

Comment: @Mike Спасибо огромное.
Да, там лишняя запятая, я упустил момент в котором менял запрос и просто забыл убрать запятую. В конечном результате "," там нет.